# C++ IDE Eclipse

Tags: c++, ide, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for a C++ IDE, typically for debugging purpose. In particular, where I can navigate in source code; say method definition, member declaration etc.

I am a Java developer and use Eclipse. I create J2ME project in Eclipse, build it and finally deploy it at same place. At the time of debugging I can easily trace out what I am looking for.

For C/C++ support I installed plug-in "Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools".
After installing above plug-in, C/C++ code open with font/style/color...but not able to navigate :(

Please help me.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cdt plugin from eclipse works fine for me. Perhaps you should update to the latest version and make sure you change your perspective to c++.

Another great c++ ide is qtcreator.

Comment: hi dorien, first of all sorry! For the delay...I am using Eclipse-Ganymede and being installed CDT-5.0 plug-in...now I am able to Create C++ project and build it at same...further need to explore it...if u don't mind then please send me your personal email id (yahoo/gmail) so that I can directly ask with u my problems regarding CDT and Eclipse....